# Mail send without subject in linux

Tags: linux, sendmail

Can anybody please help on this,

I am getting email with out subject when I use the command,

```
mail -s "subject" emailid < content.txt
```

Is there anything wrong with this command?

Comment: You have to understand what `mail`  command are you using.

Comment: There are multiple variants of the `mail` command.  Maybe yours doesn't use `-s` to set the Subject: header.  Which platform are you on?  The most portable solution might be to depend on a better-defined MSA such as `mutt` or `ssmtp`.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
[root@host ~ ]# mail -s "test" me@gmail.com
This will be in the body of the email
Cc: me_cc@gmail.com
.
[root@host ~ ]#
```

The `.` on its own line tells the mail command that you are done writing the body of the email and acts as an `EOF` for the command.

another way

```
[root@host ~ ]# echo "This will be the body of the email" | mail -s "This is the subject"   me@gmail.com
```

hope it works. Works on my machine. Please ensure that sendmail application is installed and working correctly.

```
EDIT
```

for Sun OS try this

```
echo "Hello World" | mailx -s "Hello World Test" emailaddress.com
```

Comment: @Rajeesh..as per my understanding -s flag doesn't work on SunOS with `mail` command , so you shud try `mailx` instead of mail, see my edited code.

Answer (score 1):

use `mailx` instead of `mail` as i guess you are using sun os.